# How to trigger an event after a timer runs down if the user does not click a control

Tags: c#, timer

I'm new to stackoverflow so please forgive any protocol transgressions.
I'm trying to put together a 'times tables' practice program for my grand-daughter using c#. I'm very new to programming (just past the 'Hello World' stage). I have a 'greetings' form set up where the user (my grand-daughter, usually but not always) is asked for her name and, on pressing the Enter key, is greeted with a Textbox containing a friendly message and a request to click on the message if she'd like to 'play'. If she clicks, she is taken to a combo-box where she can choose a 'game'. I would like to attach a timer to that Textbox which shows another Textbox if she doesn't click within, say, 5 seconds. I have got as far as attaching a Timer to the form and enabling it, but cannot work out what to do next. This is the code I have so far:

```
private void playerOneNameTextbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
                greetingsTextbox.Visible = true;               
                greetingsTextbox.Text = "Hi, " + playerOneNameTextbox.Text +
            ". It's good to see you. Click here if you'd like to play with us";

            timer1.Enabled = true;

            /*If there is no click within five seconds, 
             *another textbox should become visible offering another chance to click.
             */                                              
        }

        private void greetingsTextbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            youHaveClickedLabel.Visible = true;
            chooseGameComboBox.Visible = true;
        }
```

Apologies if this question is too wordy - please let me know if it is and I'll try to be more succinct next time. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included any details on how the timer has been set up (or what type of Timer it is, as I believe there are several).

I'm going with the assumption that you've designed the form through Visual Studio and have dragged in a Timer from the Toolbox.

This being the case, it should be a System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer object.

This type of timer has a Tick event which you will need to associate to an event handler. In VS you would do this by right-clicking on the timer1 object (located at the bottom of the design window) and selecting Properties. In the resulting properties window, click on the Events button (which looks like a lightning bolt). In here you'll have the one event "Tick".

Double-click on this and it'll automatically create the event handler stub code which you can then modify to do what you require with it.

You may wish to change the value of Interval on the timer1 object as this is the length of time (in milliseconds) which would elapse before it fires the Tick event, so in your case you'd want it to read 5000.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ceisc. Yes, you're right about the type of Timer - I took it from the toolbox, changed the properties (name and duration) and, based on your advice, I've now created the stub code. And that's where I still get stuck. It seems ridiculous but I just can’t come up with anything that works.

Comment: Just to let you know, Ceisc, I found out where I was going wrong - I needed to put a 'timer start' on the key up event which displayed the greeting (not 'timer enabled'). All is now working just as I want it to.